# How to loop arithmetic operators in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to loop arithmetic operator in this following code:

```
num_input = input("Please enter a number: ")
num = int(num_input)

# Define the mathematical operations as a list of tuples (operator, operand)
operations = ['+','-', '*','%']

print(f"You entered: {num_input}")
print("The mathematical operations applied to your number and 15 are:")

# Initialize an empty list to store the results
results = []

# Iterate through the operations and calculate the results
for operand in operations:
    op= [operand.strip() for operand in operations]
    result = (num) op 20     
    results.append(result)

# Iterate through the results and print them
for i, (operator, operand) in enumerate(operations):
    print(f"{num} {operator} {operand} = {results[i]}")
```

So, I just want to achieve the goal like:

When I input any integer, the code can loop calculation: *this input number* [+,-,*, %] a fixed number(say 20.)

However, if I directly use the code result=(num) operand 10, the operand is '*' instead of *, so it does not work.

I am trying to strip '' from the operator by turns and then assign it to op, and let op to do the calculate then assign the value to "result". But I still got the error like this:

Cell In[103], line 16
result = (num) op 20
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Can anyone give some help how to achieve the goal to loop arithmetic operator correctly in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Are you hoping to get 4 results from this (4+20, 4-20, 4*20, 4/20)?  Or are you hoping to get one results that is somehow chained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the operations as lambda functions to use later. For instance, you could say `operations = [lambda a, b : a + b, lambda a, b : a - b, lambda a, b : a * b, lambda a, b : a % b]` and then say `operand(num, 20)`. In this case you're calling it as a function, but it'll still do the same thing as you intend.

Comment: Another way is to use the dunder methods of int, you can create a mapping from the operators to the dunders. Ex. `operations = {"+": int.__add__, "-": int.__sub__, "*": int.__mul__, "/": int.__truediv__}`

Comment: @DaNubCoding no, you should *absolutely not use those*. Consider: `int.__add__(1, 3.14159)`. Those are meant to be used as *hooks by the runtime data model*.

Answer (score 3):

Or using the `operator` modules (which is probably what you should do)

```
import operator

num = int(input("Please enter a number: "))

# Define the mathematical operations as a list of tuples (operator, operand)
operations = {'+': operator.add, '-': operator.sub, '*': operator.mul, '%': operator.truediv}

print(f"You entered: {num}")
print("The mathematical operations applied to your number and 20 are:")

# Initialize an empty list to store the results
results = []

# Iterate through the operations and calculate the results
for name, op in operations.items():
    results.append(f"{num} {name} 20 = {op(num, 20)}")

# Print the results
print("\n".join(results))
```

Answer (score -6):

Try [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval):

```
>>> operand = '+'
>>> input_number = 1
>>> fixed_number = 10
>>> eval(f'{input_number}{operand}{fixed_number}')
11
```

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to use `eval` in code when it can be avoided using other more programmatic and thoughtful methods.